# Is there any special setting in Plugins for Injections

Tags: java, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Im working at an Eclipse 4 RCP application and I implemented an Plugin for Console output. Its designed for injection inside other Plugins so that i have only one console (The Injection was an wished feature). Its still working for already existing plugins so at all it should work everywhere. But before this plugin I implemented another Plugin and also wanted to use the new console there. Now, with same Syntax and Imports i get nothing.

Note: also tried to inject the ESelectionService as test if it depends on my own plugin but its also null

The class for the Console:

```
@Creatable //With org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Creatable
@Singleton //With javax.inject.Singleton
public class TextConsoleLogger implements ITextConsoleLogger{
...
}
```

and for injection I use the normal

```
@Inject
```

from javax.inject.Inject

Is there any setting inside an Pluggin which i have to set to inject Objects?

Thanks for help :D

As it still works in old Plugins ("old" = already written/created by other Developer) i already tried with comparison and takking different settings so i got no more ideas :/

Comment: Only things that are created using `org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory` are injected. That includes objects in the Application.e4xmi and some extension points with an `inject` argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I should be more precise. I have my own class, annotated with @Creatable. It is injected in another plugin, call it plugin B. In Plugin C I want to do exactly the same, but the field annotated with ```@Inject``` is always null. Then I tried to get some known eclipse model classes to be injected in PLugin C (e.g. ```@Inject ESelectionService```) but this is also always null. So I think I am doeing something wrong. Any suggestions? I tried to compare Manifest.MFs but they look rather equal ...

Comment: As I said the injection will only work if the plug-in B class was created using ContextInjectionFactory - so if the was a e4 MPart it would work, if it is just a plain Java class created with `new` it will not be injected.

Comment: Hi greg. Understood now! I tried with ```ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyObject.class, context);``` and it is working now. So to be precise: The new operator is replaced with a call to a static method.. In any way: Tnanks a lot!